# Synonymize [ast] with [abstract-syntax-tree]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

While typos should not be synonymized, abbreviations should be. AST is short for *'Abstract Syntax Tree'* in the context of language design.

I propose that [ast](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ast) be made a synonym of [abstract-syntax-tree](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-syntax-tree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no objection, it's clearly correct, and we're unlikely to get the votes together to approve it, I have created this synonym now.